# Почему возникает ошибка "package org.example.web.client is not visible", хотя модуль подключен?

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, gradle, jar

Разрабатываю в [intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea), необходимо подключить модуль собранный в [jar](/questions/tagged/jar)-архив (модуль мой, подключать через `mvn repository` не вариант).

Модуль подключен, IDEA не выдает ошибок, в подключенных модулях отображается, но при попытке запустить программу выдает ошибку. Пробовал указать модуль в `module-info.java` выдает ошибку: "модуль не обнаружен" (PS: вставил для примера при запуске строчки с подключением библиотеки не указывал). Сама ошибка заключается что [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) не может его прочитать (текст ошибки приведен ниже).

Первый раз пробую подключать библиотеки, но при подключении ее же в консольном варианте без [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx) все работает. Буду рад любой помощи, в том числе ссылочкам на литературу, где можно об этом почитать в интернете решения найти не удалось.

В строке ниже у меня возникла ошибка

```
//Module not found: org.example.web.client    
requires org.example.web.client;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно Вас понимаю, Вам требуется подключить собственную библиотеку без использования репозитория maven.
В данном случае, нужно подключить библиотеку к проекту следующим образом.

```
Project Settings > Modules > Dependencies > знак ‘+’ > JARs or directories…
```

Далее указываете путь до собственной библиотеки, затем переходим в *module-info.java*, и указываем библиотеку через `requires`.

Использовал, для примера, сторонюю библиотеку `javadbf`.  Можно искать с помощью предложенных IDE вариантов.

```
requires com.github.albfernandez.javadbf;
```

И далее импортируем уже в требуемый нам класс:

```
import com.linuxense.javadbf.DBFReader;
```

После всё должно работать. Если же нет, то возможно что Ваша библиотека могла быть скомпилирована как "Runnable jar file". Подключал к проекту JavaFX.